# Convert compiled code back into source code

Tags: python, compilation, bytecode

I have an obfuscated Python code object that has been encoded and compressed using various modules, including base64, zlib, gzip, and marshal.

My goal is to reverse engineer this code object in order to extract the original source code.

Here's the process I used to generate the obfuscated code object:

```py
import gzip, zlib, marshal, base64
pycode = "print('Hello world')"
obfuscated_code = base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(gzip.compress(marshal.dumps(compile(pycode, <string>, "exec"))), level=zlib.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION))
```

Then I made following to run the obfuscated python code for running..

```py
import gzip, zlib, marshal, base64

exec(marshal.loads(gzip.decompress(zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(obfuscated_code)))))
```

I tried changing exec to print.
However, instead of printing the source code, the output I received was:

```bash
bash<code object <module> at 0x15034df59df0, file "Nice Try", line 1>
```

My question is: How can I reverse engineer this code object to successfully extract the original source code?

Is there a way to recover the source code from the given obfuscated code object?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: *"I compiled python code to bytecode."*. No, you didn't.

Comment: Which challenge are you doing?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Im not doing a challenge. Can you help ?

Comment: It is hard to infer what you are trying to do. Please clarify, by editing the question.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I rephrased question please read again

Answer (score 2):

**Here's your corrected code:**

```
import zlib
import gzip
import marshal
import base64

# Your Python source code
pycode = "print('Hello world')"

# Compile the code
compiled_code = compile(pycode, "Nice Try", "exec")

# Serialize and compress the compiled code
compressed_code = zlib.compress(gzip.compress(marshal.dumps(compiled_code)), level=zlib.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION)

# Encode the compressed code in base64
encoded_code = base64.b64encode(compressed_code)

# print the encoded code
print(encoded_code)

# Decode the base64-encoded code
compressed_code = base64.b64decode(encoded_code)

# Decompress the compressed code using zlib
gzip_compressed_code = zlib.decompress(compressed_code)

# Decompress the gzip-compressed code
bytecode = gzip.decompress(gzip_compressed_code)

# Unmarshal the serialized bytecode
compiled_code = marshal.loads(bytecode)

# print the compiled code
print(compiled_code)

# Execute the compiled code
exec(compiled_code)
```

Output:

```
b'eNoBZgCZ/x+LCACIfOxkAv97zIAGmIDYAYiLeYBEKkMKQzMjI0MKYzCDJlMVt0dqTk6+Qnl+UU6KnybjLdaCosy8kpUMRSBNYOIXh19mcqpCSFHlLQ6b3PyU0pxUO0ag+GeQ0QBLaA7pbAAAADlZKhY='
<code object <module> at 0x7fcfc14d6920, file "Nice Try", line 1>
Hello world
```

Here are two more ways that will enable you to decompile your bytecode but you will need the raw .pyc or .pyo file to decompile it back to the source code.

#### Solution 1

I suggest you use the `uncompyle6` package, if you're are using `python <= 3.6`.

- You can install from PyPI:

```
pip install uncompyle6
```

- You can use it from the command line like this:

```
uncompyle6 path/to/bytecode/file.pyc
```

- Or if you want to use it from a python script:

```
import subprocess

def decompile_pyc(pyc_file_path):
    try:
        command = ["uncompyle6", pyc_file_path]
        result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
        decompiled_code = result.stdout
        return decompiled_code
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        return None

# Provide the path to your .pyc file
pyc_file_path = "__pycache__/test.cpython-38.pyc"

# Call the function to decompile the .pyc file
decompiled_code = decompile_pyc(pyc_file_path)

# Print the decompiled code
if decompiled_code:
    print(decompiled_code)
```

Check out https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6 to know more

#### Solution 2

If you are using `python-3.7` or `python-3.8` check out  `decompyle3`. The usage is basically the same as before:

- You can install from PyPI:

```
pip install decompyle6
```

- You can use it from the command line like this:

```
decompyle6 path/to/bytecode/file.pyc
```

- Or from a python script

```
import subprocess
def decompile_pyc(pyc_file_path):
    try:
        command = ["decompyle3", pyc_file_path]
        result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
        decompiled_code = result.stdout
        return decompiled_code
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        return None

# Provide the path to your compiled .pyc file
pyc_file_path = "__pycache__/test.cpython-38.pyc"

# Call the function to decompile the .pyc file
decompiled_code = decompile_pyc(pyc_file_path)

# Print the decompiled code
if decompiled_code:
    print(decompiled_code)
```

Check out https://github.com/rocky/python-decompile3 to know more.

Comment: Doesn't work either of it.

Comment: It's working on my end here.  As mentioned in the answer, you have to have python<=3.8 so should be the bytecode. Is your `.pyc` path correct? are you getting any errors? or anything else?

Comment: Also I corrected your code and added it to my answer, check that too. I'm running on `python3.8.16`

Comment: This works only to pyc files and not codeobjects. Tried converting code objects to py c and doing this but not works.

Comment: Check your corrected code in the fist answer, I added it there.

Comment: you cannot convert codeobjects to `pyc` file. The corrected code with output is added in the answer too